# Using TopoR with EagleCad

Tags: pcb, routing

I just learnt of TopoR routing software. It routes PCB traces without grids, with curves and arcs for reduced trace length and vias.

http://www.toporouter.com/

But its not a complete PCB routing solution , they have examples on how to use it with DipTrace.

At work we all use and are comfortable with EagleCad . Has anybody used TopoR with Eaglecad? or know of EagleCad plugin/user script that kinda does the same.

Comment: The [Electra](http://www.konekt.com/) autorouter is available for Eagle and many other packages. I use the version supplied with Pulsonix, it's excellent.

Comment: I know this discussion took place a while ago, however I'd like to invite you all to the English speaking forum related to TopoR.
If you have any questions regarding this tool, feel free to ask them there :)
http://forum.eremex.com/

Answer (score 3):

Pretty interesting.  Every auto router i've ever used has been terrible with anything but the simplest boards, including OrCad and Altium (tho i love Altium for a lot of other reasons).  This looks like it may be worth playing with.

Anyway, according to their website:

"TopoR supports standard Specctra DSN/SES interface that most CAD systems have. Also TopoR can import/export P-CAD and PADS ASCII formats."

I don't think eagle supports Specctra DSN/SES, at least last i knew, so you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried TopoR from Eagle but I have used freerouting.net which also requires a dsn file as input.  The freerouting.net site instructions pointed to the ULP script brd_to_dsn.ulp, which can create a dsn file from an Eagle brd file.  I would guess that process would also work with TopoR.

freerouting.net is also worth looking at as an alternative autorouter for Eagle.  One thing to note, which might be relevant to TopoR as well, is tha brd_to_dsn.ulp doesn't do the right thing with ground planes (copper filled polygons) from Eagle so I've ended up putting those in after freerouting.net has done the routing.  The same might be true with TopoR.

Comment: thnx Scott, that brd_to_dsn.ulp worked prefectly. I was able to turn eagle's brds to dsn files and import it in TopoR.

Comment: now all I need is an ulp that can import SES files exported by TopoR back into eaglecad.

Comment: Please don't mark this answer as accepted since it doesn't fully answer the question (no info on how to import SES into Eagle). If you mark it accepted, then other people are unlikely to come and offer more help.

Comment: Do you actually need to import back from TopoR?  If TopoR can export gerbers, for example, then you could imagine a workflow where you do the schematic capture in Eagle, export to TopoR and do the routing and produce the gerbers (or perhaps pdf or whatever output you need).  It depends on what, exactly, you are trying to do.

Comment: I have yet to find an autorouter that didn't need any touching up after it has finished the job.  So in all likelihood, you'll want to take the design back into Eagle.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing [this](http://www.eremex.com/products/topor/competitiveadvantages/compatibility.html) is their parent company's site?

> This allows to use TopoR with many other PCB CAD Systems which support SPECCTRA DSN format, such as Elektra, Altium, Pulsonix, **Eagle**, DipTrace, etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this forum post](http://www.element-14.com/community/message/15753), you can export DXF from Topor, and then use dxf2scr to convert the DXF to a SCR file, then load the SCR file into Eagle. There are 3 different apps that convert DXF to SCR listed on [cadsoft's website](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/cgi-bin/download.pl?page=/home/cadsoft/html_public/download.htm.en&dir=eagle/userfiles/misc), try them and report back which one works best.

Comment: Lol I'm the guys in the form who asked that question.

Comment: Ok so dxf2scr is not working for me. I tried running the SCR it generates in a empty brd files.. and nothing happens. I looked at the dxf file that topor generates with a third part dxf viewer and it looks fine.  The description for dxf2scr says it only does "board outlines from AutoCAD to Eagle" so it may not import the routing anyway.
I tried dxf2scr-1 , its look like its just a clone with a gui , and it doesn't work too.

Comment: the DXF importer from EagleCad power tools, seems to be the only one that kinda works. It presemnts me a list of layers in the dxf and how they should be transfered to eaglecad like top to layer 1 , bottom to layer 16. But when i run it it only seems to translate the pads and not the traces and routing. Could be because I'm running it in demo mode.

Answer (score 0):

This will be much more feasible when [Eagle switches to a text-based file format](http://www.element-14.com/community/message/15751#15751).  Converters should show up once this happens, and you can then use another piece of software to do the routing.

If I remember correctly, gEDA also has some support for topological autorouting.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a crude SES-to-SCR converter for my own use. It supports a subset of SES (2 layers, only wires and vias) with a bunch of limitations, but it does the trick for me. If you are interested, go ahead and give it a try:
http://www.element-14.com/community/thread/5588 (scroll down)

Matthias

Comment: Matthias - This *does* provide a way to use TopoR with EagleCad, but it's not obvious from your answer.  Please keep your answers as complete as possible on this site, without a dependency on external links (especially links which require scrolling).  Note that the Eagle rep was similarly worried about the link expiration.

Comment: Also, please don't add a tagline to your answers.  You've already got a profile link in the lower right corner, and a whole profile on which to express yourself.  Signature lines are highly discouraged: I won't edit it this time (since I'm hoping you'll edit it yourself as described by my previous comment), but please refrain from the practice in the future.